# Check if text file in directory to show direct

Tags: ios, iphone

I am developing an iOS app. I download the text file from a URL and save it into a directory, but I can't find the file in the directory, so the code downloads it again. How do I check for the file?

```
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:localfile]) {
         content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:localfile
                                            encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                               error:NULL];
    }else
    {
        NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://webapp.opaxweb.net/books/gurugranthsahib.txt"];

    NSArray* pathArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                             NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString* documentsDir = [pathArray objectAtIndex:0];
    localfile =[documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data"];
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    [data writeToFile:localfile atomically:YES];
    content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:localfile
                                        encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                         error:NULL];
}
_textfield.text=content;
```

Comment: Your code is correct but maybe you are not retaining the localfile string properly.  Just NSLog the localfile string before checking fileExistsAtPath method and also check in the actual Documents Directory, whether files exists or not.

Comment: Please stop using double dots and make your question clear. I edited useless talk out.

Answer (score 1):

Your text data is quite big and hence you should use nsurl connection! Your code is totally correct but this is a better approach.

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        self.fileName = @"Data";
        self.fileData = [NSMutableData data];
        [self checkFileExitsorNOt];
    }

    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
    {
        [self.fileData setLength:0];
        self.totalFileSize = [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:[response expectedContentLength]];
    }

    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
    {
            [self.fileData appendData:data];        
    }

    - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
    {
        NSArray *dirArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,    NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSLog(@"%@", [dirArray objectAtIndex:0]);

        NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [dirArray objectAtIndex:0],self.fileName];

        if ([self.fileData writeToFile:path options:NSAtomicWrite error:nil] == NO) {
            NSLog(@"writeToFile error");
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Written!");
        }
    }

-(void) checkFileExitsorNOt
{
    NSArray *dirArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,    NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSLog(@"%@", [dirArray objectAtIndex:0]);

    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [dirArray objectAtIndex:0],self.fileName];

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path]) {
        NSString  *cont = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:localfile
                                                    encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                       error:NULL];
        NSLog(@"Content from file : %@",cont);
    }
    else
    {
        NSString *file = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://webapp.opaxweb.net/books/gurugranthsahib.txt"];
        NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:file];

        NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:fileURL];
        NSURLConnection *conn = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:req delegate:self];
    }

}
```

Comment: Sounds a bit expensive, but it might be the officially supported way of streaming data from a file (please clarify).  A cheaper option is to use old school C file APIs.

Comment: please clarify what you mean by "A cheaper option is to use old school C file APIs."

Comment: Using `fopen()`, `fgets()`, etc.